# How do I get a Flutter release iOS app onto my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I want to test a release build of my Flutter 1.9 iOS app on my iPhone without going through the App Store. The development build from IntelliJ runs just fine on my iPhone, but I want to see the real performance characteristics.

The [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive) describes how to build a release version of the app. This creates `build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app` in my project. But how can I get `Runner.app` from my Mac onto my iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried `flutter run --release`? I mean running in release mode?

Comment: No, not yet. I will. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `flutter run --release -d [device name]`, you can run the Flutter app in release mode either in a simulator or on a real device. Thank you, [Chenna Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808877/chenna-reddy)!